# Fatal error: Call to a member function getAllVisibleItems() on a non-object in

Tags: magento-1.9

we are trying to send Abandoned cart email , we are getting errors as below :

**Fatal error: Call to a member function getAllVisibleItems() on a non-object in**
line

```
<?php foreach($this->getOrder()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item): ?>    
<a href="<?php echo $item->getProduct()->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $item->getName() ?></a>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I was working before one month, is any other code conflicting ? no log errors.

please give me some idea how i can solve this....

**edit**

```
protected function _getBaseProducts($parent)
    {
        $result = array();

        if ($parent->getOrder()) {
            foreach ($parent->getOrder()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                $result[] = $item->getProduct();
            }
        }

        if ($parent->getQuote() && count($result) == 0) {
            foreach ($parent->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                $result[] = $item->getProduct();
            }
        }

        if ($parent->getCustomer() && count($result) == 0) {
            $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $parent->getCustomer()->getId());
            foreach ($orders as $order) {
                foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                    $result[] = $item->getProduct();
                }
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

**block**

```
class Mirasvit_Email_Block_Cross extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{
    public function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->setArea('frontend');
        $this->setTemplate('mst_email/cross.phtml');

        return $this->renderView();
    }

    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
}
```

Comment: provide block type for your phtml

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala please check updated question

Comment: @BabyinMagento for better answer please add some more code/details -  especially where/how you want to get the related order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `$this->getOrder()` in your phtml file your block class `Mirasvit_Email_Block_Cross` has to have a `getOrder()` method *(that is instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`)*.